# Javascript closures. strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, function, closures

Reading this article:

http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/

I found something I don't understand about closures.

This, for example:

```
function celebrityName (firstName) {
    var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";
    // this inner function has access to the outer function's variables, including the parameter​
    function lastName (theLastName) {
        return nameIntro + firstName + " " + theLastName;
    }
    return lastName;
}

var mjName = celebrityName("Michael"); // At this juncture, the celebrityName outer function has returned.​

// The closure (lastName) is called here after the outer function has returned above​
// ​// Yet, the closure still has access to the outer function's variables and parameter​

console.log(mjName("Jackson")); // This celebrity is Michael Jackson
console.log(mjName);
mjName("test");
```

Returns:

```
This celebrity is Michael Jackson
[Function: lastName]
```

But i don't understand why if I add another closure:

```
function celebrityName (firstName) {
    var nameIntro = "This celebrity is ";
    // this inner function has access to the outer function's variables, including the parameter​
    function lastName (theLastName) {
        return nameIntro + firstName + " " + theLastName;
    }
    function firstNameFunc (theLastName) {
        return nameIntro + theLastName + " " + firstName;
    }
    return lastName;
}

var mjName = celebrityName("Michael"); // At this juncture, the celebrityName outer function has returned.​

// The closure (lastName) is called here after the outer function has returned above​
// ​// Yet, the closure still has access to the outer function's variables and parameter​

console.log(mjName("Jackson")); // This celebrity is Michael Jackson
console.log(mjName);
mjName("test");
```

I get this result:

```
This celebrity is Michael Jackson
[Function: lastName]
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

Why this is happening? I understand that the call return the closure because it value is stored inside the variable but, in the second case it returns only the first closure.

Thank your very much!

Comment: You’ve got a typo: `firstNamey`. You never call `firstName`, you just append it like that and if you append a function to a string, the function will be stringified.

Comment: Thank you @Xufox! I corrected the call and changed the function name to "firstNameFunc". Now i don't get why the call (mjName("Jackson") returns only the lastName function. What about the other one?

Comment: Honestly that code is daft and excessively confusing. I wouldn't worry about it...

Comment: @S4rg0n: Nothing is done with the other one, so it is ignored. Try `return`ing it instead of `lastName`, or try to return both of them as properties of an object.